# Python html2text text issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am using `html2text` for converting Html into text,
but its also changing my text strings as well e.g `A&P` to `A&P;`

how i can avoid this change

```
In [1]: import html2text

In [2]: conv = html2text.HTML2Text()

In [3]: conv.handle("string A&P string")
P
&P;
Out[3]: u'string A&P; string\n\n'
```

output should be

```
Out[3]: u'string A&P string\n\n'
```

Comment: Which exactly html2text package are you using? There seem to be multiple tools with that name.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the string you convert has syntax error. & should be escaped in html language.

Try

```
out = conv.handle("string A&amp;P string")
```